# Find time of highest and lowest candles

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to draw a box from the highest candle to the lowest in the last 20 candles.
Each box has 4 side: top, bottom, left and right.
for top and bottom i use highest() and lowest() but for left and right how can i find time for highest and lowest candle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the high using highest and low using lowest function. Then you can find the index of them using barssince function. Then you can use them to plot a box at the last bar using barstate.islast. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Highest Lowest Bar", shorttitle="HLB", overlay=true)

hi=ta.highest(high,20)
lo=ta.lowest(low,20)
hiIndex=ta.barssince(high==hi)
loIndex=ta.barssince(low==lo)
var box b=na
if barstate.islast
    box.delete(b)
    b:=box.new(bar_index-hiIndex,hi,bar_index-loIndex,lo,bgcolor=color.new(color.blue,80),border_color=na)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the times in variable when a new highest/lowest is detected
Also, you have the choice in the box.new variable to use bar_index too.
Giving you the example using "times"

```
var int time_high = 0
var int time_low = 0

current_highest = ta.highest(20)
current_lowest = ta.lowest(20)

// If new High/Low
if (current_highest != current_highest[1])
   time_high := time

if (current_lowest != current_lowest[1])
   time_low := time
```

Comment: thanks but for past how could draw box? your script calculate for now not the past